# Is it possible to link README file in javadocs?

Tags: android, javadoc

I currently use my README file as a set of instructions, and would like to refer to it in javadocs. I know it is possible to link directories in javadoc, for example to link an image I can do

```
/**
 * <img src="../../../images/Diagram.png"/>
 */
```

But how to link the README file that is under the project root? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the AdoptOpenJDK Collection [source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java), it looks like the HTML anchor `<a></a>` tag is used to link to files in various parts. For example on lines 192-193, there's:

```
<a href="{@docRoot}/java.base/java/util/package-summary.html#CollectionsFramework">
Java Collections Framework</a>.
```

You can also see this in other javadoc comments throughout the source code as well so you should be able to use the path to the non-Java class file you want to link to with the anchor tag.